# Retrieving "Description" or "Custom Attribute" fields using Autodesk Forge API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

We are trying to retrieve the description or custom attribute field as shown in BIM360 Docs using Autodesk Forge API requests/commands.

We have tried the following requests to retrieve information about a specific file:

- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-GET/
- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/ListItems/

We get a lot of information/data about our files, but we cannot see the Description field neither a Custom Attribute in the responses that we are getting.

```
"data": {
        "type": "versions",
        "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.WKuhlYuyR8uK2WT8HE1bCQ?version=20",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "TESTING",
            "displayName": "TESTING",
            "createTime": "2019-07-29T09:37:33.0000000Z",
            "createUserId": "*****",
            "createUserName": "TESTING",
            "lastModifiedTime": "2019-08-05T08:27:10.0000000Z",
            "lastModifiedUserId": "*****",
            "lastModifiedUserName": "TESTING",
            "versionNumber": 20,
            "storageSize": 27020,
            "fileType": "xlsx",
            "extension": {
                "type": "versions:autodesk.bim360:File",
                "version": "1.0",
                "schema": {
                    "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/versions:autodesk.bim360:File-1.0"
                },
                "data": {
                    "processState": "PROCESSING_COMPLETE",
                    "extractionState": "UNSUPPORTED",
                    "splittingState": "NOT_SPLIT",
                    "revisionDisplayLabel": "20",
                    "sourceFileName": "TESTING"
                }
            }
        },
...
}
```

Among all of these fields, we expected the fields "Description" or "Custom Attributes" to appear as well (As they are shown in BIM360 DOCS). ¿Is it possible to retrive these fields using API requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment it is not possible to retrieve Custom Attribute information from BIM 360 Docs, But a new API is under development and in Private Beta testing at the moment to get this information back, Please check back with us in a near future since this will become available soon. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: any update on that? I still don't see custom attributes in ForgeAPI GET Request ```https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/:project_Id/items/:item_id``` ?

Comment: I see this endpoint being available, This will retrieve the Custom attribute definition value. https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/document-management-custom-attribute-definitions-GET/

Comment: Hello @JaimeRosales
This endpoint retrieves the definition of the custom properties, but what about the values of them?

Comment: @mustafa.salaheldin
[POST versions:batch-get](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/document-management-versionsbatch-get-POST/)
You may try this endpoint to retrieve the attribute values.