# Get file description from BIM360

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I am trying to retrieve the file description column from BIM360, but cannot seem to find an endpoint that makes this possible.
I found a question from 2019 about this, saying it was under development, is there any known progress regarding this:
[Retrieving "Description" or "Custom Attribute" fields using Autodesk Forge API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57355330/retrieving-description-or-custom-attribute-fields-using-autodesk-forge-api)

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestion

Answer (score 2):

I hate to disappoint you, but it is true Description field has not been exposed by the API. We have had a wish ticket: FDM-3124. We are pushing engineer team to implement.

It is not a good workaround, while it might be way you create one custom attribute and input description there. API with custom attribute is available.
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-attributes-apis-bim-360-document-are-now-public-beta

Thank you for your patience waiting for API to expose Description.

Comment: Sad news indeed, but happy to hear that it is something you are pushing for. 
Are the tickets publicly available somewhere, so we can follow what is currently being considered, and maybe in what order they are being considered?

Comment: Still without any news about this?

Comment: What's the priority of this ticket on your board? this links to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76738664/autodesk-construction-cloud-get-file-description-attribute which is now 2 years on for the same issue.