# Autodesk Construction Cloud - Get file Description attribute

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-construction-cloud

Surely there is a way to read the description attribute of a file in Docs using the API?!?!

It isn't returned using this endpoint as it isn't a custom attribute:
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/document-management-versionsbatch-get-POST

nor this one:
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET

Surely this is a critical attribute for any kind of integration?

[image: ACC Description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not exposed currently, it's a known issue and the wish is logged as FDM-3124 already. Sorry for the inconvenices.

Comment: Surely not :( . I saw a post from a few years ago saying this was logged but it has not been actioned since then. Adding a custom attribute for an existing property is so confusing to end users. Is there any timeline for this? It must be a small update.

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have a timeline for this, APS Date Management API needs support multiple Autodesk SAAS include BIM 360, A360, Fusion360, ACC, some properties conflicted, that might be the reason for taking time, but I will raise this request again for engineering team's awareness.

Comment: ok, thanks Zhong, its just seems a key piece of data for any integration with another system.

Comment: @ZhongWu has there been any update on getting this property exposed?

Comment: @ZhongWu, I'm working currently on a similar project and really shocked when I discovered that the custom attributes and the description are not coming along.
This is an urgent request please!!!

Comment: Hi Mustafa, sorry for that, let me put your comments for the request for the update.